# Scale down Bitmap values

Tags: java, android, bitmap

In order to classify an image I greyscaled it and by using Bitmap.getPixels I managed to extract the values.
But the classifier takes only valuess from 0 to 1.
I am using API 21.

My approach would be that a white pixel is 0 and the darker it gets the values become higher to a certain max value(for example 128 which would be black). If this works like that I could scale the values by deviding by the biggest possible number(128 in the example) so that black equals 1 and white 0. So I need to know the highest possible value(maybe any get function?).

To get that value I first just took a black picture which gave me a negative value (around -16000). I tried it once again with a non black picture and the value was over +500000.

What does the negative value mean? How does the colourvalue system work with bitmaps?

If you have any approachs or ideas please let me know.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: why don't you just search for `android bitmap to grayscale`?

Comment: Because it is already a grayscaled Bitmap. That works just fine. The Problem is how the extracted values behave.

Comment: Bitmap.getPixels returns values within sRGB color space. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorSpace.Named.html#SRGB